# How do I insert a new line immediately after a subparagraph?

Tags: line-breaking, sections-paragraphs

I'd like to add a line immediately after a subparagraph as by default it does a weird bend that I don't like.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.5em}{0pt}
    \section{SECTION}
    \subsection*{SUBSECTION:}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi persequeris nam ut. His ut facilis atomorum incorrupte, nam liber gubergren adolescens ne, vis no unum utamur.
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

This is what happens:

`1 SECTION
    SUBPARAGRAPH: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi 
  persequeris nam ut. His ut facilis atomorum incorrupte,
  nam liber gubergren adolescens ne, vis no unum utamur.`

Instead of that I'd like:

`1 SECTION
    SUBPARAGRAPH: 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi persequeris nam ut.
     His ut facilis atomorum incorrupte, nam liber 
     gubergren adolescens ne, vis no unum utamur.`

How can I do this?

Comment: use `subsection*`, not `subparagraph`.

Comment: @Zarko It still aligns with the section unfortunately.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your document class?

Comment: I use the Article class.

Comment: @user9549355, sorry, this is not clear from your question. please edit it and better explain your problem. the best way is with small but complete document, which begin with `\documentclas{...}` and end with `\end{document}`.  as it seems you like to redefine `sections`, `subsections` ... styles. a rude and dirty trick is insert empty line between your `subparagraph` and following text. however this solution is far from be good. i wouldn't do this.

Comment: @Zarko I edited the question.

Comment: `\subparagraph` is a level 5 heading and should only be used after `\section...\subsection..\subsubsection..\paragraph`

Comment: Perhaps see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8121/15925

Comment: i've answered this question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/558743/222098